# Filter specific rows of worksheet C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, filter, epplus

I'm currently trying to get specific rows of an Excel file in my code.
I get the data of my Excel file with this code:

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(local_in_file_path);
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
                int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
                List<string> testlist = new List<string>();
                List<string> articlelist = new List<string>();
                for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {

                        testlist.Add(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim());
                        foreach (var i in testlist)
                        {
                            if (articlelist.Contains(i))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                articlelist.Add(i);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach (var article in articlelist)
                {
                    var rows = worksheet.Row().Where(n => n = article); //doesnt work 
                }
```

In the foreach loop I want all rows, in which the specific article occurs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because when you add something to `testlist` you are picking only 1 cell everytime (so if your excel file is structured like "1 row has 'article name' , 'description' ecc you are running through every col in every row so it's pretty inefficient, if you could only provide an example of your excel file we can try to help, and does that foreach create an exception or something else?